# Can I create a Hyper-V VM template of a stand-alone SharePoint installation?

Tags: 2013

Recently I've setup multiple VMs for SharePoint 2013 development. I'm using the stand-alone installation. Now I want to create a template.

I ran sysprep and exported the machine. But when I create a new VM from it I get errors such as "Failed to detect if this server is joined to a server farm...".

Is it possible to create a VM template for a stand-alone installation? Is anyone doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot template SharePoint VMs after you've run the Config Wizard. So what you can do is install SharePoint, without running the wizard, then sysprep.

An end-to-end guide has been posted on the [TechNet Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emberger/archive/2014/09/09/sharepoint-sysprep.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up your OS to auto run [AutoSPInstaller](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) on first boot after your SysPrep?  It takes more clock time for the first boot than a template VM, but not any more interaction.  What are you trying to optimize?